Redis instaltion failure
Facing issue in instalation Redis software (Memurai-Developer-v4.1.2.msi), I get error as follows "memurai develop setup wizard ended prematurely" and not getting installed. I have been admin for the sysytem. PLease advise.
Regards,
Damodaran
Mobile : 8939886460

Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

This is not related to Redis, you should investigate logs of the app (memurai)

Usually this is related to access problems. Try running it from command line started with admin privileges.
This might be helpful: https://docs.memurai.com/en/installation.html
